# Finding $x$ values of tangents from derivatives with literal coefficients

Tags: derivatives

Given $$f(x) = ax^2 (2x-1)^{-1}=\frac{ax^2}{2x-1}$$ find the $x$ values where the tangent is horizontal. Show all steps and express the derivative in simplified form.

Comment: Yes! I think I have gotten the question, but my only concern is that is the 'a' value used in any way in the answer? I got x values of 0 and 1

Comment: So I found the derivative, made that equal to zero, so 0 = [2ax(x-1)]/(2x-1)^2 and then solved for x, which I got 0 and 1, the only part throwing me off is the 'a' which I didn't use

Comment: Ohhhh I used the quotient rule, and now I tried the product rule, but I can't get the derivative that you got

Comment: Sorry, my derivative was wrong, I'm tired and used $f(x) = ax^{2}(2x - 1)^{-2}$ by accident. Your derivative is fine. And so is your result that your critical points (also known as stationary or turning points) are at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. The $a$ has no influence on our turning points. Your solution is correct.

Comment: That's no problem! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: rebecca, i edited my answer. you may want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value $a$  does not not matter in finding the horizontal tangent because both the graphs $y = f(x), y = af(x)$ have the horizontal tangents at the same pints. it is also clear that at $x = 0, y = \frac{x^2}{2x - 1} = -x^2 + \cdots$ has a horizontal tangent. the graph of $y = \frac{x^2}{2x - 1}$ has a vertical asymptote at $x = \frac 12, y > 0, \frac 12 < x < 1$ and too $\lim_{x \to 1/2+} y= \infty, y = \frac 12 x + \cdots$ at $x = \infty$ that means there must be a horizontal tangent in $1/2 < x < \infty.$

it may be easier to do the derivative by implicit differentiation. that is $$y(2x-1) = ax^2 \to (2x-1)\, dy + 2 dx \, y = 2ax \,dx $$ setting $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ gives $$ax = y = \frac{ax^2}{2x-1} \to ax(x-1) = 0 \to x = 0, x = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you Abel, I haven't fully learned implicit differentiation in school yet, but from what I know about it that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Rebecca, you will get there with the quotient rule too. here is how you do that. take $u = x^2, v = 2x - 1.$ then $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac u v \right) = \frac{v\frac{du}{dx} - u\frac{dv}{dx}}{v^2} = \frac{(2x-1)2x - x^2(2x-1)}{(2x-1)^2}$ since $x \neq 0,$ set the numerator to zero. and you can go from there.